# Showing that a polynomial splits in a splitting field of another polynomial

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field with characteristic $p \gt 0$ and let $q(x) = x^p-ax-b \in k[x]$ be a polynomial with $a \neq 0$. Let $K$ be a splitting field of $q(x)$. I have to prove that $x^{p-1}-a$ splits in $K$.

What I was able to do -  If we assume $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{p-1}-a$, then $a\alpha$ is also its root. Now all I have to prove is that $\alpha \in K$. This part actually seems easy but somehow I am unable to tackle this problem.

Comment: If $c$ and $d$ are distinct roots of $q(x)$ then $c-d$ is a root of $x^{p-1}-a$ right?

Comment: Please, for the sake of an aged mathematician with failing eyesight, never use $\alpha$ and $a$ in the same equation; and certainly never next to each other.

Comment: @Lubin Ok sir! Thanks for the big help